# Reading in a file causes issues when character r is present

Tags: ruby

I have a function that reads in an input test file so that I can do further processing. For some reason it is treating my r as a carriage return `\r`

```
def main
    #format input
    input = []
    File.foreach(ARGV[0], 'r') do |f|

        puts "f is #{f}"
        break
    end
end
main()
```

testfile.csv

```
149
u,6,3
b,11,11
r,10,11
h,4,8
t,4,5
v,7,9
```

However whenever an r is encountered in my test file no further output is read in. For some reason r is treated as a carriage return `\r`

commandline

```
> ruby bst.rb testfile.csv 
f is 149
u,6,3
b,11,11
r
```

Comment: I think you're confusing `File.open` with `IO.foreach`.

Comment: That may be possible. I was unaware of IO class until after I posted this. From what I've read online so far, it looks as though the File class is a subclass of IO. The solution below worked for me. Though I am still confused about why foreach even worked here. Am I iterating over a stream of characters here?

Comment: How is it possible? You were using it-and the edit makes the comments and answers referencing it nonsensical.

Comment: Good point. I guess it's not possible. My last comment didn't come out how I meant it to. I was simply trying to concede a point and admit my ignorance on this matter. I apologize if what I said was confusing. Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below way

```
File.foreach("C:/Users/rajarshi.das/Desktop/abc.csv","rb") do |f| 
  puts "f is #{f}"
  break
end
```

output

```
   >> f is 149
    u,6,3
    b,11,11
    r,10,11
    h,4,8
    t,4,5
    v,7,9
```

replace `r` mode to use `rb` mode or `r+` mode

```
File.foreach("C:/Users/rajarshi.das/Desktop/abc.csv","rb")
```

or

```
File.foreach("C:/Users/rajarshi.das/Desktop/abc.csv","r+")
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the docs for [`IO.foreach`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/IO.html#method-c-foreach). The second argument is the separator to use to split up lines, *not* the open mode for the file (it could also be the limit—the max length string to return).

This means in your call to `foreach` you are asking Ruby to return strings from the file separated by the `r` character, which is exactly what you are seeing.

The solution is to drop the `'r'`, read only mode is the default so you don’t need it:

```
File.foreach(ARGV[0]) do |f|
  #...
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why `File.foreach` is splitting on the carriage return nor why it's finding one there. But functionally speaking all you're doing is reading the text of the file, and for that there are alternatives:

```
puts File.read("test.csv")
# or
File.open("test.csv", "r") { |f| puts f.read }
```